# Searching in an array indexed in ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have indexed a document in `ElasticSearch` that contains arrays like this:

```
{
    "student": "John",
    "sport": "Soccer",
    "match": 
    {
        "eventType": "League",
        "date": "2013-12-31T11:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

I need to perform a query that searches for, for example, all league matches (ie, where `doc["match"]["eventType"] == "League"`)

I am using the `ElasticSearch-PHP api 1.1.0` and tried querying as such as this without success:

```
$params['body']['query']['match']['match']['eventType'] = 'League';
```

I also tried:

```
$params['body']['query']['match']['match']->eventType = 'League';
```

What is the correct way to do such a search? The documentation has no such examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you convert this JSON to php object?

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "match.eventType": "League"
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will do the work.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly.  For reference, the PHP looks like this: `$params['body']['query']['match']['match.eventType'] = 'League';`

Answer (score -1):

As a first step, try to use a different name for your soccer 'match' and call it 'game' to prevent causing a collision with the use of the 'match' operation.

Comment: This is not an answer to the Question